# UsersAdapter in Usersadapter cannot be applied to (...)

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to learn to show an array of article links in a ListView. I get this error message when trying to create an adapter to convert the array items into views.

```
Error:(62, 36) error: constructor UsersAdapter in class 
    HovedSide.UsersAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
    required: Context,ArrayList<HovedSide.User>
    found: HovedSide.UsersAdapter,ArrayList<HovedSide.User>
    reason: actual argument HovedSide.UsersAdapter cannot be
    converted to Context by method invocation conversion
```

Source code:

```
public class HovedSide extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hoved_side);
    }

    public class User {
        public String article;

        public User(String article) {
            this.article = article;
        }
    }
    public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            User user = getItem(position);
            view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_list, parent, false);
            }
            TextView articlename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvarticle);
            articlename.setText(user.article);          
            return convertView;

            ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
            UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this,arrayOfUsers);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            User newUser = new User("Article1");
            adapter.add(newUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Error in:

```
UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this,arrayOfUsers);
```

Tried replacing it with following, as other posts suggested;

```
UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(),arrayOfUsers);
```

Comment: Firstly, make your `UserAdapter` static or better yet, move it out into its own .java file. Your problem is that you've put lots of classes in one small pot. Secondly, it's a very clear issue with incompatible types. Your adapter's constructor needs a `Context` (such as `Activity` instance), and you're passing it an adapter. Conclusion: please break down your problem into small parts to make things easy for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I test your code in Activty and that works fine. 
in `AppCompatActivity`  you have to use something like this :

```
getApplicationContext()
```

### Update

I tried in v7 and that was fine too . this is my code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

        arrayOfUsers.add(new User("usr 1"));
        arrayOfUsers.add(new User("usr 2"));
        arrayOfUsers.add(new User("usr 3"));

        UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayOfUsers);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        User newUser = new User("Article1");
        adapter.add(newUser);

    }


    public class User {
        public String article;

        public User(String article) {
            this.article = article;
        }
    }
    public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            User user = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_list, parent, false);
            }
            TextView articlename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvarticle);
            articlename.setText(user.article);
            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @MiguelPedersen `That did not work for me` this does not help. What exactly did not work? What did it say?

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried to use 'getApplicationContext()' instead of 'this'. That did not work.

The error dissapeared from `UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayOfUsers);`

But another error appeared in `ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();`

It says "Unreachable statement"

I have yet to try your UPDATE.

Comment: you add definition of arrayOfUsers  in getview after return. look at my code .do it like that.

Comment: @MiguelPedersen I would be honest and blunt - you must get familiar with Java before starting with Android. "unreachable statement" is very clear, Google it if you need to know a bit more about it. Your main problem isn't Android specific but rather it's basic Java. I'd again highly recommend you to practice Java before resuming with Android.

Comment: @Sufian Thank you. I'm too stubborn so I'll probably just learn by trials and tribulations with Android. I'm sure It'll work out.

Comment: @mehdazizi Thank you. Moving the code from the array data from the Adapter method into the OnCreate() method made this work.